# Login multiusuario con diferentes ROL

Tags: php

tengo una web, donde hay un único login que redirige según usuario. Ahora lo que quiero agregarle es que sea según usuario y rol, ya que debo filtrar más aun. Tengo un archivo llamado `autenticar.php` donde hace todo el trabajo. El tema que al agregar el rol a cada usuario guardado en la MySQL, a la hora de redireccionar a los sitios, me dice que no encuentra el sitio.

`autenticar.php` funcionando sin rol:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("conectar.php");

if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
header('location: ../Comedores_Totaltes/'.$_SESSION['name']);
} else {

if ( !isset($_POST['el_usuario'], $_POST['la_clave']) )
{
exit('Llenar todos los campos!');
 }
 }
 if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID, clave FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?'))
 {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['el_usuario']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
 
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
  {
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $clave);
  $stmt->fetch();
            
  if(password_verify( $_POST['la_clave'],$clave))
  {
  session_regenerate_id();
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['el_usuario'];
  $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
  header('location: ../Comedores_Totales/'.$_SESSION['name']);
  }
```

los roles son (Personal, Administrador, Sistemas). Le agregue en el archivo trayendo el rol de la BD según usuario.

`autenticar.php` agregando el rol:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once("conectar.php");

 if(!empty($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
  header('location: ../Comedores_Totaltes/'.$_SESSION['rol']."/".$_SESSION['name']);
  } else {

 if ( !isset($_POST['el_usuario'],$_POST['rol'], $_POST['la_clave']) )
 {
 exit('Llenar todos los campos!');
   }
   }
  if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID, clave, rol FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = ?'))
  {
   $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['el_usuario'], $_POST['rol']);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->store_result();
 
   if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
   {
   $stmt->bind_result($id, $clave);
   $stmt->fetch();
            
   if(password_verify( $_POST['la_clave'],$clave))
   {
   session_regenerate_id();
   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
   $_SESSION['rol'] = $_POST['rol'];
   $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['el_usuario'];
   $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
   header('location: ../Comedores_Totales/'.$_SESSION['rol'].'/'.$_SESSION['name']);
   }
```

No entiendo porque no me lo toma, en la URL me figura el rol asignado del usuario, pero no me muestra el índex de ese usuario, alguna idea? os agradeceré!

Comment: Por lo que dices, el código redirecciona pero el navegador te indica que no puede encontrar la página. Siendo así, lo más probable no es que tu código esté mal, sino que las direcciones que indicas en los `header()` son incorrectas.

Comment: En cualquier caso, no tiene demasiado sentido guardar las variables en la sesión para luego pasarlas a través de la URL: simplemente vas a la dirección de *Comedores_Totales* (sin pasarle el rol o el nombre), inicias la sesión y trabajas directamente con las variables de `$_SESSION`

Comment: lo que si note, es que en cada web, necesita ingresar con el usuario para visualizarla, sino te redirecciona al login, al agregar el "rol" me ingresa sin solicitar el usuario

Comment: el tema de las url es raro, porque la url es la misma, pero no accede al index.. sera que tengo que agregar algo en el index?

Comment: No sabría decirte, si todas las URL van a través del index.php de tu web, habría que ver cómo interpretas en tu código los enlaces para saber por qué no los encuentra.

Comment: Veo errores de sintaxis, en una parte pones `Comedores_Totaltes` y en otra parte pones `Comedores_Totales`, revisa eso. Por otra parte, me pregunto si no es mejor usar URLs amigables o algo así, redirigiendo a un punto de entrada según el rol, teniendo así URLs del tipo: `www.tudominio.com/personal` o `www.tudominio.com/administrador` o `www.tudominio.com/sistemas` según el caso y haciendo que tu `index.php` sea una especie de Controlador. Y, no entiendo qué pintan aquí las variables de sesión ¿?

Comment: Gracias, no me di cuenta del error de sintaxis. Explico un poco mejor, no es un solo index. Sino que del rol "personal" van a ver muchos usuarios y cada uno tendrá su index. no hay relación entre ellos. Lo que pensé es que tengo a lo mejor es comparar si el usuario tiene el rol de "personal" guiarlo a la sección de personal y según su usuario tendrá su index. No sé si funcionara de esa forma?

Comment: Vale, lo resolví.. agrego EDIT

Comment: Tenes un rato en el sitio y sabes como funciona.. las respuestas, van en el campo respuestas, bien explicadas...

Comment: No sabía que si encontraba la respuesta, la tenía que poner como respuesta a mi propia pregunta.. Lo cambio, disculpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, me funciono como lo había pensado. Muestro como me quedo el codigo:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once("conectar.php");

 if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ID, clave, rol FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = 
  ?'))
 {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['el_usuario']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
 
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0)
  {
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $clave, $rol);
 $stmt->fetch();
            
 if(password_verify( $_POST['la_clave'],$clave))
 {
 session_regenerate_id();
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
 $_SESSION['rol'] = $rol;
 $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['el_usuario'];
 $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
 header('location: ../Comedores_Totales/'.$rol.'/'.$_SESSION['name']);
 }
```

Muchas gracias por los consejos, me ayudaron a ver la solución.